# Errors: grub-efi-amd64-signed & shim-signed

Tags: linux

pI need to fix the following problems

*I do not have experience in linux, so please possible give me simply explanations and the code to type in command line and fix the problems, please!*

I checked other threads and I found similar problems but non the same.

**Question**

```
manolis@manolis-300-0xx:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  netplan.io
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.93.8+2.02-2ubuntu8.7) ...
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Could not prepare Boot variable: No space left on device
grub-install: error: efibootmgr failed to register the boot entry: Input/output error.
dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 installed grub-efi-amd64-signed package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for shim-signed:
 shim-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64-signed; however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64-signed is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
 shim-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**Backgournd Informations**

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.1 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic

manolis@manolis-300-0xx:~$ echo ${BASH_VERSION%%[^0-9.]*}
4.4.19

manolis@manolis-300-0xx:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1,9G     0  1,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           387M  2,0M  385M   1% /run
/dev/sda2       916G  207G  663G  24% /
tmpfs           1,9G   61M  1,9G   4% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1,9G     0  1,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      3,8M  3,8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51
/dev/loop2       88M   88M     0 100% /snap/core/5742
/dev/loop1       15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/45
/dev/loop4      141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
/dev/loop6       13M   13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/117
/dev/loop7       13M   13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/124
/dev/loop9      140M  140M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/64
/dev/loop10      35M   35M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/319
/dev/loop8      2,3M  2,3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/238
/dev/loop5      128K  128K     0 100% /snap/tree/15
/dev/loop11     3,8M  3,8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/54
/dev/loop12      13M   13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/139
/dev/loop13      88M   88M     0 100% /snap/core/5662
/dev/loop3      2,3M  2,3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/260
/dev/loop14      43M   43M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/701
/dev/loop15      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/43
/dev/loop16      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/40
/dev/loop17     141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74
/dev/loop18      88M   88M     0 100% /snap/core/5548
/dev/loop19     2,3M  2,3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/222
/dev/loop20     3,8M  3,8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
/dev/sda1       511M  6,1M  505M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs           387M   40K  387M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb1       1,9T  108G  1,8T   6% /media/manolis/Maxtor
tmpfs           387M   16K  387M   1% /run/user/120

manolis@manolis-300-0xx:~$ sudo apt install udo
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  udo
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 205 kB of archives.
After this operation, 598 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 udo amd64 6.4.1-4 [205 kB]
Fetched 205 kB in 0s (1.520 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package udo.
(Reading database ... 168775 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../archives/udo_6.4.1-4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking udo (6.4.1-4) ...
Setting up udo (6.4.1-4) ...
Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.93.8+2.02-2ubuntu8.7) ...
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Could not prepare Boot variable: No space left on device
grub-install: error: efibootmgr failed to register the boot entry: Input/output error.
dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 installed grub-efi-amd64-signed package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for shim-signed:
 shim-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64-signed; however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64-signed is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
 shim-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Why I have all of these "/dev/loop" ???
How can I clean and increase the space: "Could not prepare Boot variable: No space left on device"

Is correct to do, or dangerous:

rm -r /dev/loop*

All the best!

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions.  This is a general problem and a better forum to ask this is https://askubuntu.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/.  For example,  https://askubuntu.com/questions/990013/system-mounts-dev-loop0-on-snap-core-3604-and-its-100-full-where-is-it-comi or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/406534/snap-dev-loop-at-100-utilization-no-free-space might help you out.

Comment: After performing steps in Linux Mint 19 I've lost grub and wasn't able to boot in Mint any more. Be careful and backup before reinstalling grub.

Comment: Possible duplicate (and answer): https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231781/errors-encountered-while-processing-grub-efi-amd64-signed-and-shim-signed-p/1485099#1485099

Also do *not* `rm` your dev folder! /dev means `devices` and are mappings to your hardware. These don't take up any space at all. Try `du -d 1` from /dev and everything will show zeros.

(I also ran into this problem when I ran out of disk space, so it could be caused by an aborted installation that left the system in an unstable state, e.g. with the /boot/efi unmounted permanently)

Answer (score 51):

**The following worked well for me on Ubuntu 18.04LTS**

*on the following commands : use sudo or run as root*

```
sudo apt-get purge grub\*
sudo apt-get install grub-efi
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo update-grub
```

-or-

```
sudo su
```

*enter your password then run*

```
apt-get purge grub\*
apt-get install grub-efi
apt-get autoremove
update-grub
```

Comment: This also worked after upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04, thank you

Comment: Just had the same problem and used the commands to solve it. There is a related bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg/+bug/1871963

Comment: Small modification to your commands above - after purging the grub packages I did a `sudo apt-get install grub-efi-amd64-signed` instead of `sudo apt-get install grub-efi`. I believe the signed packages include the CA certificate needed to allow secure boot in the BIOS settings. This could make a difference if this option is enabled.

Comment: In my case, the EFI partition(for me /dev/sdc1) was not mounted correctly to /boot/efi since as it was missing in /etc/fstab. This can be checked with output of `df -Th` is missing `/boot/efi`. After mounting it the package installed correctly and issue disappeared.

Comment: This fixed the issue while updating a long out of date 20.04 image for an AtomicPI dev board. Thx.

Answer (score 11):

In my case, Ubuntu 18.04 installed on bare metal servers, I had to execute this command:

```
apt-get install -y grub-pc 'grub-efi*-'
```

which yielded this change:

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  grub-gfxpayload-lists grub-pc-bin
Suggested packages:
  desktop-base
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  grub-efi-amd64 grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed shim-signed
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  grub-gfxpayload-lists grub-pc grub-pc-bin
```

After this, the error is gone.

Comment: This is what helped me on 18.04.5

Comment: Helped on 20.04.2

Comment: grub-efi-* was giving trouble even with all those "apt purge ..." commands mentioned in the other reply.  This seems to use another package and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

These 2 lines of command worked for me.

```
 apt install grub-efi-amd64-bin
 apt upgrade
```

Comment: After purging, issuing first and separatedly this commands worked for mew

Answer (score 2):

If you're here in 2023 and experiencing this issue with Github actions checkout [this](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/47863) discussion.

Current work around is to mark the package to hold back any update attempts using:

```
sudo apt-mark hold grub-efi-amd64-signed
```

Credit: [(MyreMylar) Dan Lawrence](https://github.com/MyreMylar) for the solution.

Comment: Holding both `grub-efi-amd64-signed` and `shim-signed` was necessary to fix my issue upgrading ubuntu from 22.10 to 23.04.  `sudo apt-mark hold shim-signed grub-efi-amd64-signed`.  Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @spazm urgh finally. I was trying hours to get upgraded. It was a mistake to install a non-lts version to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough rep to add a comment, but the answer from "AAA SSS" worked for me.  I found the same answer in the [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763472/what-can-i-do-to-fix-this-error-on-grub-efi) forum.  I was directed there by pasting this into a Google search.

```
Package grub-efi-amd64-signed is not configured yet.
```

My situation arose from both a fresh install to 18.04 **and** an upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04, the same errors printed by apt and booting failed.  "dpkg -l" reported these errors.

```
iF grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.93.13+2.02-2ubuntu8.12)
iU shim-signed (1.37~18.04.3+15+1533136590.3beb971-0ubuntu1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The above attempts were not working for me.

I was getting similar errors, not sure what happened on me, but my /etc/default/grub file had an extra line added during a recent update:

"/etc/default/grub" 34L, 1279C

was at the bottom of that file, I commented it out and things worked for me again!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've installed OS with `secure boot` disabled, but now it is enabled.

Make sure you still have the `secure boot` option disabled in BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

Run this as one command and answer y (yes) when prompted:

```
sudo apt-get purge grub\*
sudo apt-get install grub-efi
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo update-grub
```

This just a quicker way base off the answer given by [AAA SSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53284186/217867). This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had problem which says

```sh
dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 installed grub-efi-amd64-signed package post-installation script subprocess ret
urned error exit status 127
```

I found that It's beacuse of bugs which can solve installing `mokutil`

```sh
sudo apt-get install -y mokutil
```